Can't boot ARM64 devices with iPXE
I'm testing a new dell ARM64 laptop with iPXE, but despite that it's able to pxe boot, it's not able to load the http iPXE boot menu as configured. All of our machines are either BIOS or UEFI-based and those machines are able to successfully boot with iPXE and load the iPXE Boot Menu. I was hoping replicating my current dnsmasq configuration for BIOS/UEFI devices would work with ARM64, but no go. In addition, the ipxe .efi file for ARM64 was compiled with the latest build. Thank you in advance.
About my server:

Rocky Linux release 8.10 (Green Obsidian)
Dnsmasq version 2.79  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 Simon Kelley

Dnsmasq.conf configuration:
##### # enable tftp server
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/tftpboot

##### # dhcp proxy mode. do not act as the authoratitive dhcp server
dhcp-range=192.168.1.0,proxy,255.255.255.0

##### # send disable multicast and broadcast discovery, and to download the boot file immediately
dhcp-option=vendor:PXEClient,6,2b

##### # set tag ENH if request comes from iPXE (iPXE user class)
##### #dhcp-match=set:ENH,175 # alternative way, look for option 175
dhcp-userclass=set:ENH,iPXE

##### # if request comes from firmware, load iPXE via TFTP
pxe-service=tag:!ENH,X86-64_EFI, iPXE Boot (UEFI), ipxe.efi
pxe-service=tag:!ENH,X86PC, iPXE Boot (BIOS), undionly.kpxe
pxe-service=tag:!ENH,ARM64_EFI, iPXE Boot (ARM64), ipxe_arm.efi

##### # if request comes from iPXE, direct it to boot from boot.ipxe
##### # dhcp-boot=tag:ENH,http://192.168.1.21/boot.ipxe
pxe-service=tag:ENH,X86-64_EFI, UEFI: ipxe.efi - iPXE, http://192.168.1.21/menu/bootuefi.ipxe
pxe-service=tag:ENH,X86PC, PC-DOS: undionly.kpxe - iPXE, http://192.168.1.21/menu/bootbios.ipxe
pxe-service=tag:ENH,ARM64_EFI, ARM64: ipxe_arm.efi - iPXE, http://192.168.1.21/menu/bootarm64.ipxe

##### # enable logging
log-queries=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
#log-dhcp=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log

Dnsmasq log file:
##### #The log shows a bios-based machine (192.168.1.33) pxebooting and loading the boot menu.
##### #The ARM64 laptop (192.168.1.150) fails to load the boot menu.
Sep 18 17:35:00 dnsmasq-dhcp[17377]: PXE(ens18) 08:00:27:8c:3f:8g proxy
Sep 18 17:35:00 dnsmasq-dhcp[17377]: PXE(ens18) 08:00:27:8c:3f:8g proxy
Sep 18 17:35:03 dnsmasq-dhcp[17377]: PXE(ens18) 192.168.1.33 08:00:27:8c:3f:8g undionly.kpxe
Sep 18 17:35:05 dnsmasq-tftp[17377]: error 0 TFTP Aborted received from 192.168.1.33
Sep 18 17:35:05 dnsmasq-tftp[17377]: failed sending /tftpboot/undionly.kpxe to 192.168.1.33
Sep 18 17:35:05 dnsmasq-tftp[17377]: sent /tftpboot/undionly.kpxe to 192.168.1.33
Sep 18 17:35:07 dnsmasq-dhcp[17377]: PXE(ens18) 08:00:27:8c:3f:8g proxy
Sep 18 17:35:07 dnsmasq-dhcp[17377]: PXE(ens18) 192.168.1.33 08:00:27:8c:3f:8g http://192.168.1.21/menu/bootbios.ipxe
Sep 18 17:35:52 dnsmasq-dhcp[17377]: PXE(ens18) d8:ec:5e:71:cf:05 proxy
Sep 18 17:35:55 dnsmasq-dhcp[17377]: PXE(ens18) d8:ec:5e:71:cf:05 proxy
Sep 18 17:35:56 dnsmasq-tftp[17377]: error 8 User aborted the transfer received from 192.168.1.150
Sep 18 17:35:56 dnsmasq-tftp[17377]: failed sending /tftpboot/ipxe_arm.efi to 192.168.1.150
Sep 18 17:35:58 dnsmasq-tftp[17377]: sent /tftpboot/ipxe_arm.efi to 192.168.1.150
Sep 18 17:35:58 dnsmasq-tftp[17377]: sent /tftpboot/autoexec.ipxe to 192.168.1.150


Have you any logs from your ARM laptop?

Hi paladin. Thank you for the follow-up. I didn't check the log, but did manage to resolve the issue. Needed to re-compile a arm64 ipxe.efi file, but first needed to modify two other files (general.h and console.h) to allow the console to work and load the boot menu. Once the two files were modified, then I compiled a new ipxe.efi file: make CROSS=aarch64-linux-gnu- bin-arm64-efi/ipxe.efi
